# Create a shared album combining photos from multiple OneDrive accounts belonging to the same family group

Tags: onedrive, photo-sharing

Recently we went on a family trip and everybody was taking pictures. We all are part of a Onedrive family plan.

How we can create an single album that includes everyone's photos?

Do we each need to upload them into a single account or are there "family album" settings somewhere I cannot find?

I am new to OneDrive. I found out how to share my albums with a person, but this is a bit different as I want to merge albums from multiple accounts from our family group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

You all need to upload them to the same shared OneDrive folder.

---

You **can** share a OneDrive folder with your family group and they **can** add their own photos to that folder if you give them sufficient privileges.

You **can** share a OneDrive album with your family group however they **cannot**  add photos to that album.<sup>*****</sup>

---

<sup>*****</sup> `Fixes or workarounds for recent issues in OneDrive > "Items weren't added" error when uploading to a shared album`

Comment: ok, I see, I will try, thank you. I hoped inside family they had some shared functionality as it makes sense when a family goes on a trip or have an event they can organise a shared gallery without uploading to a second place.

Comment: @Mykola I think this is a case of a storage app trying to wear too many hats. A dedicated cloud-based photo app like Google Photos (there are others) would likely be a better fit for album sharing.  [Best photo storage and sharing sites of 2024](https://www.techradar.com/best/best-photo-storage)

Comment: Ok, I guess this is the only way. I have Amazon Prime and can use it for photos, but I hoped to have all files in one place - the documetns and the media files. Thank you!